# Overlaying GeoServer based WMS on a Map

Tags: html, geoserver, wms

First of all I would like to say that, I am beginner level in terms of any web programming languages. I am trying to build a very basic map with some gis based vector layers overlaid on top of it. I created a point layer on  Geoserver with FarmerMarkets name in Mapabase workspave. However I cannot transfer these points on top of map by using HTML. I provided the code below. If you guys can help me I would be grateful.
Cheers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Eko eko ses</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>

L.mapbox.accessToken = <my token>;
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', <>)
    .setView([40, -75], 11);
 
 // Add the WMS      
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
  "WMS", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Mapabase/wms",
  {
    LAYERS: 'Mapabase:FarmersMarkets',transparent: true
  },
  {
    singleTile:true,
    isBaseLayer: false,
  }
);
map.addLayer(layer);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the problem was basically disparity between the reference systems of map and WMS. So it is solved.